# Java: Thread.sleep mousepress delay

Tags: java

I've been trying to create an autoclicker in java using jnativehook.
It works fine, even compiles and runs. My problem is using `Thread.sleep` to try and add a delay between clicks:

```
bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
Thread.sleep(50);
bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

If I were to input a delay of 0 it will function fine. But given no delay it will click too fast.
When I add a delay it will click fine but, when I release the trigger key it will keep clicking for a few seconds given the time it's been clicking. A delay of 0 will not do this however.

Full code:

```
public class App implements NativeKeyListener{

private JPanel panel1;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1;
private JButton spoilerButton;
private JSlider slider1;
private JSlider slider2;

//Removed irrelevant code...

static Robot bot;

static {
    try {
        bot = new Robot();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static boolean pressed;

public void click() throws InterruptedException {

    try {

        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}

@Override
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    if (NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()) == "Delete") {
        pressed = true;
        while (pressed){
            try {
                click();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }}

@Override
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    if (NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode())=="Delete"){
        pressed=false;
    }}

@Override
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Autoclicker");
    frame.setContentPane(new App().panel1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400,148);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    try{GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (Exception e){
                System.exit(1);}
    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new App());

}
}
```

Comment: I'd second Rajeev in the suspicion that this is multi-threading related. I am not sure if his suggestions would work though. But also, I am not sure if I understand, what you are trying to do here. My understanding (please confirm/correct): Key pressed -> Mouseclick (press & release) shall be simulated repeatedly. Key released: Clicking shall stop.

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Then I would recommend a combination of a Thread and [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) that will be set on the respective events. That is: You would make a Thread with an infinite loop executing the click-sim. BUT: It will block waiting for a condition - let's call it "activated". So, you won't have an infinite spin-wait. Then you'll check for a AtomicBoolean to be true. If it is execute the click-sim, if it is not wait for the condition again.

Comment: keyPressed would then set the AtomicBoolean and notify the condition, keyReleased would just reset the AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the method nativeKeyPressed() gets called continuously when you keep pressing the trigger key. This results in several calls to click() method (assuming it's multi threaded) and due to the sleep() between mouse press and release (mouse click is complete when released) this can happen.

Hence you can try two options depending on the root cause:
1. move the sleep() call after mouse released. If the nativeKeyPressed gets called concurrently this won't work.
2. Use a different thread to execute the click() method when trigger is pressed. In this case, you may need to submit a Runnable object to your thread each time with the 'pressed' check and click() call in it. This will ensure it won't run after pressed becomes false.